# Table is not mapped Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to connect to Oracle with hibernate however I'm getting exception that table is not mapped. I tried to use XML files and annotations. The result was the same. Here is code:

Table name in database - NOWA

NOWA.java

```
    package entity;

public class NOWA {
    private int id;
    private String imie;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Nowa{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", imie='" + imie + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getImie() {
        return imie;
    }

    public void setImie(String imie) {
        this.imie = imie;
    }
}
```

NOWA.hbm.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="entity">
    <class name = "NOWA" table = "NOWA">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
            <generator class="assigned"></generator>
        </id>

        <property name="imie" column="IMIE" />

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping resource="entity/NOWA.hbm.xml" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Controller.java

```
    package sample;

import entity.NOWA;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private ListView<NOWA> tabela;


    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        Session session = HibernateFactory.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<NOWA> lista = session.createQuery("from NOWA ").list();
        tabela.getItems().setAll(lista);
        for (NOWA a: lista
             ) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Exception:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erTnh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must move your hbm to the resources folder so that it is visible in the classpath.

Your complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">***</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping resource="entity/NOWA.hbm.xml" />

        <mapping class="entity.NOWA" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

After Debugging your code I have finding a bug in the your HibernateConfiguration, this is the code correct

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {


            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder standardServiceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            standardServiceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = standardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure().build();

            return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
```

you never called configure on standardServiceRegistryBuilder.

I have updated this answer and the pull-request

This [pull request](https://github.com/poldeeek/pasjaInf/pull/1) fix your problem

Comment: I have a stupid question for you, you have a Database inside your oracle? if yes, could it be that the db saves the table in lowercase and can't find your NOWA because it's nowa for him? for example, postgress uses this method, oracle I don't know

Comment: I have 2 databases but every tabel is uniuque. I tried with tabel Uczen before and it was the same problem.
https://ibb.co/Bfg8PPr - how my Oracle database looks like

Comment: move the NOWA.hbm.xml inside the resources dir and  change the `<mapping resource="entity/NOWA.hbm.xml" />` to `<mapping resource="NOWA.hbm.xml" />`

Comment: still nothing... :/

Comment: @poldeeek  I added the answer with the solution, if I work to thank I would accept an upvoted, thank you

Comment: I changed names of files from NOWA to Nowa and added 

        List<Nowa> lista = session.createQuery("from entity.Nowa ").list();

But this time i got this : WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from entity.Nowa

Comment: the name change is just a good refactoring, which leads to significant changes in your implementations, so now fix the error and don't change the name to anything.
My pull-request is executable and the application runs without any major problems

Comment: you have to change the name also in the xml and in everything you carry around, look at my pull request and work on that project structure

Comment: I downloaded your fixed exception commit and changed only hibernate.cfg.xml. Still i got that exception :

WARN: HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from entity.NOWA

when i remove this entity, the problem is that Nowa is not mapped....

Comment: I have found a bug in the position hbm and your HibernateFactory, I have updated the answer and I create pull-request for fix this bug

Comment: @poldeeek an upvodet to comments is the best thanks here on stackoverflow if I have been helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        
        
        ***
        thread

```
    <mapping resource="NOWA.hbm.xml" />



</session-factory>
```

Comment: is your mapping file is in any package or not?